# git: ask confirmation on double `git add`?

Tags: git

Sometimes `git add`ing a file that already have staged changes can lose history I wanted to keep.

Is there any way to get a confirmation dialog or some other signal when I do that by mistake?

Comment: Commit more often. Commit before re-adding. Best way to not "lose history".

Comment: i agree. but I still would like "protection" from forgetting to commit something that was staged.

Answer (score 5):

Not from Git itself, no.

You could stop using `git add` directly though, and run a program you write yourself.  Make an alias (`git a`) or name it `git-a` and put it in your path so that `git a` invokes *your* program, which reads more or less as:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

# compute all-zero null hash ID (git rev-parse should have a flag for this!)
zeros=$(git hash-object --stdin </dev/null | sed 's/./0/g')

confirm=false
for arg do
    # if file is modified in staging area WRT HEAD commit, confirm
    headrev=$(git rev-parse "HEAD:$arg" 2>/dev/null || echo $zeros)
    indexrev=$(git rev-parse ":arg" 2>/dev/null || echo $zeros)
    if [ $headrev != $indexrev ]; then
        echo "warning: $arg is modified in index"
        confirm=true
    fi
done
if $confirm; then
    echo -n "add anyway? (y/n) "
    read yn
    case "$yn" in
        y|Y|yes|YES);;
        *) echo "not adding"; exit 1;;
    esac
fi
git add "$@"
```

This script is entirely untested, so test first.  Note that this is deliberately simple, too: it does not handle the same flag arguments as `git add` and won't process `git add .` properly; for that you must work much harder.